# jquery scrollto() new xy position of $(this) after window height dynamically changes

Tags: jquery, this, scrollto, window.location

**INTRO**

I'm using the following code to expand and minimize divs when clicked. When the page first loads all divs are minimized.

**JQUERY**

```
$(".listtitle").click(function(){
    $(".listbox").animate({height: "65px" }, 400)
    $(this).parent(".listbox").animate({"height":$(this).parent().get(0).scrollHeight},400);
    $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top}, 400);
});
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm lead to believe $(this) window xy coordinates of any div below the first div clicked are lost.

I believe this because if I click on the bottom div first, then the next div above it and so on, it works as it should, but if I click on a div above another first then the next div below it, it does not work.

**SEE JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ChDdE/3868/

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to establish the xy cordinates of window.location everytime a div is clicked. or should I think in another direction?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a separate function and calling the scroll2 function at the end of the script. It is important to note that I created a variable for $(this).offset() which is different from the original $(this).parent().offset().

**NEW CODE**

```
$(".listtitle").click(function(){
 $(".listbox").animate({height: "65px" }, 400)
 $(this).parent(".listbox").animate({"height":$(this).parent().get(0).scrollHeight},400, scroll2);
});

function scroll2() {
var offset = $(this).offset();
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offset.top}, 400);
}
```

**SEE JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ChDdE/3871/